# How to randomize the choices from this quiz?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to learn how to randomize the choices, I have already randomized the question and am able to add score for every correct answer.

But whenever I try to randomize the choices using Math.random on the choices and creating new variables for the choices it just wouldn't work.

```js
const question = document.querySelector('#question');
const choices = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.choice-text'));
const progressText = document.querySelector('#progressText');
const scoreText = document.querySelector('#score');
const submit = document.querySelector('.submit');
//Questions

let currentQuestion = {}
let acceptingAnswers = true; //abswer must be true
let score = 0 //question starting at 0
let questionCounter = 0; //question starting at 0
let availableQuestions = []

let questions = [{
    //Q1
    question: "Which element has the symbol 'I' ?",
    choice1: "Iron",
    choice2: "Yttrium",
    choice3: "Iodine",
    choice4: "Iridium",
    answer: 3,
  },
  //Q2
  {
    question: "Which element has the symbol 'K' ?",
    choice1: "Krypton",
    choice2: "Potassium",
    choice3: "Copper",
    choice4: "Carbon",
    answer: 2,
  },
  //Q3
  {
    question: "Which element has the symbol 'Lv' ?",
    choice1: "Lawrencium",
    choice2: "Lanthanum",
    choice3: "Lithium",
    choice4: "Livermorium",
    answer: 4,
  },
  //Q4
  {
    question: "Which element has the symbol 'No' ?",
    choice1: "Niobium",
    choice2: "Nobelium",
    choice3: "Nihonium",
    choice4: "Nitrogen",
    answer: 2,
  },
  //Q5
  {
    question: "Which element has the symbol 'Og' ?",
    choice1: "Silver",
    choice2: "Osmium",
    choice3: "Oxygen",
    choice4: "Oganesson",
    answer: 4,
  },
  //Q6
  {
    question: "Which element has the symbol 'Rb' ?",
    choice1: "Rubidium",
    choice2: "Radon",
    choice3: "Rutherfordium",
    choice4: "Roentgenium",
    answer: 1,
  },
  //Q7
  {
    question: "Which element has the symbol 'Sg' ?",
    choice1: "Selenium",
    choice2: "Strontium",
    choice3: "Seaborgium",
    choice4: "Samarium",
    answer: 3,
  },
  //Q8
  {
    question: "Which element has the symbol 'Ti' ?",
    choice1: "Technetium",
    choice2: "Titanium",
    choice3: "Thalium",
    choice4: "Tin",
    answer: 2,
  },
  //Q9
  {
    question: "Which element has the symbol 'Y' ?",
    choice1: "Ytterbium",
    choice2: "Iridium",
    choice3: "Iron",
    choice4: "Yttrium",
    answer: 4,
  },
  //Q10
  {
    question: "Which element has the symbol 'Mc' ?",
    choice1: "Mendeleevium",
    choice2: "Molybdenum",
    choice3: "Moscovium",
    choice4: "Meitnerium",
    answer: 3,
  }
]

const SCORE_POINTS = 100 //score
const MAX_QUESTIONS = 10 // limit of questions

startGame = () => {
  questionCounter = 0
  score = 0
  availableQuestions = [...questions] // get question from the questions variable every start of game
  getNewQuestion()
}

getNewQuestion = () => {

  //Keep track of the score
  if (availableQuestions.length === 0 || questionCounter > MAX_QUESTIONS) {
    localStorage.setItem('mostRecentScore', score)

    return window.location.assign('end.html')
  }
  //questions changing to next one each click
  questionCounter++
  progressText.innerText = `Question ${questionCounter} of ${MAX_QUESTIONS}` //backticks helps to contain any js expressions


  //Keep track of what question in present
  //randomizes question
  const questionsIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQuestions.length)
  currentQuestion = availableQuestions[questionsIndex]
  question.innerText = currentQuestion.question



  //Choices

  choices.forEach(choice => {
    const number = choice.dataset['number']
    choice.innerText = currentQuestion['choice' + number]
  })

  availableQuestions.splice(questionsIndex, 1) //removes element from an array by only 1 , then returns what you remove

  acceptingAnswers = true //keeps track of correct answers
}


//checking if answers are correct or incorrect
choices.forEach(choice => {
  choice.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (!acceptingAnswers) return //if the answer is wrong just continue without changing anything
    acceptingAnswers = false
    const selectedChoice = e.target //if user clicks this add the event
    const selectedAnswer = selectedChoice.dataset['number'] //the answer is the selectedchoice variable from the array's index number


    /*if the selected answer is the correct answer from the index with the variable answer then if its true
    then call the class from the CSS that changes the color accordingly if the selected answer is correct IF NOT then call the class that changes color for wrong answers*/
    let classToApply = selectedAnswer == currentQuestion.answer ? 'correct' : 'incorrect'



    if (classToApply === 'correct') {
      incrementScore(SCORE_POINTS)
    }



    selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.add(classToApply)


    //setTimeOut(function,miliseconds,...)

    //remove the color by 1 second then move on to the next question
    setTimeout(() => {

      selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.remove(classToApply)
      getNewQuestion()
    }, 1000)


  })


  incrementScore = num => {
    score += num
    scoreText.innerText = score
  }


  //Moves to the next question
  startGame()

})
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. You can update the snippet with HTML and CSS to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```
const nums = new Set();
while(nums.size !== 4) {
  nums.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1);
}
choices.forEach((choice,i) => {
  choice.innerText = currentQuestion['choice' + nums[i]]
})
```

You could have made it easier by not having choice1, choice2 etc but instead  have

```
choices = ["choice 1","choice 2"..]
```

Comment: But how will i randomize this?  guide me                                                                              choices = ["choice 1","choice 2"..]

Comment: Actually more or less the same way - my first suggestion will work for you